# Multi column table in LaTex

Tags: tables

I want to draw a multi column table in LaTeX. Please help me.

Four row and three main column. 1st column single. 2nd and 3rd column have each four sub column.

Comment: Welcome, a MWE with the things you tried is always nice ;-). On this site http://www.tablesgenerator.com you can make those tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
First Column & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Column}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Third Column}\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Particulars} &2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17\\
&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&33\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: multirowcol]